# App Engine Backend Quota Not Touched

Tags: google-app-engine, backend, task-queue, gae-quotas

I have a dynamic backend process that gets called from within my frontend app code. To do this it must be visible via app.yaml. But when the backend gets run in this way I see no change in my backend quota on the admin panel, leading me to believe it's running on the frontend quota.

The Backend is called via a `taskqueue.add(url='/path/to/backend')` from the frontend side.

Should this not invoke a backend instance for a minimum of 15 mins and thus use that quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't target a task to a backend via URL, you do it with the `target` parameter:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/my/url', target='my_backend_name')
```

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Push_Queues_and_Backends).

Comment: if I run my backend directly from cron.yaml will it run on a backend instance?

Comment: You can put a target param for the job in cron.yaml: `target: my_backend_name`

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually started the backend up via the command line?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Commands

```
 appcfg backends <dir> start <backend>
```

> Sets the backend state to START, allowing it to receive HTTP requests. Resident backends start immediately. Dynamic backends do not start until the first user request arrives. Has no effect if the backend was already started.